# Bing map container padding

Tags: javascript, css, bing-maps

I've started usage of Bing maps recently, and noticed that each and every sample has some ugly white rectangles at the top and bottom of the map (see bellow).

Does Microsoft and everyone who use Bing maps are considering this as normal? Because I haven't found any solution for this issue after a brief googling. 
I might use some self-created patch but want to ask the community first.

Thanks in advance![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is to set the background color of the map to `#ACC7F2`. This matches the color of ocean on closer zoom levels.

Usage example:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(mapdiv, {
    ...
    backgroundColor: Microsoft.Maps.Color.fromHex('#ACC7F2'),
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'll follow your advice. Though it's not actually a solution it will serve for some time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Bing lets you move the top and bottom of the map to the vertical center of the screen/container. Since you are at the top or bottom of the page, it just has to fill up with a white area.

Remember that the map is repeating horizontally, not vertically (probably since the earth is turning "horizontally".

Comment: yes, I have understood that it is not actually a 'bug', but anyway it looks terrible